# SQL Unexpected SELECT

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm dynamically constructing a query within C# based on passed in parameters. It's constructing the query correctly based off what I'm passing in yet I cannot figure out why the query keeps throwing an `Unexpected SELECT` error. The error refers to the very last select within this query, right after the group and order by.

Here is the query that is output by my program:

```
with allTables as (
    SELECT 
        UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(DATE)) as date, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN period = 7  THEN users END) AS days_07 
    FROM (
        SELECT
            activity.date AS DATE,
            periods.period AS period,
            COUNT(DISTINCT user) AS users                                                   
        FROM ( 
            SELECT 
                activity.date AS DATE, 
                periods.period AS period, 
                COUNT(DISTINCT user) AS users 
            FROM ( 
                SELECT
                    DISTINCT DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros)) AS DATE,
                    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS user 
                FROM `hidden.*` 
                CROSS JOIN 
                    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event 
            ) AS activity 
            CROSS JOIN ( 
                SELECT 
                    DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros)) AS DATE 
                FROM `hidden.*` 
                CROSS JOIN 
                    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event 
                GROUP BY event.timestamp_micros 
            ) AS dates 
            CROSS JOIN ( 
                SELECT period FROM (SELECT 7 AS period) 
            ) AS periods
            WHERE 
                dates.date >= activity.date 
            AND 
                SAFE_CAST(FLOOR(DATE_DIFF(dates.date, activity.date, DAY)/periods.period) AS INT64) = 0 
            GROUP BY 1,2 
        ) GROUP BY DATE ORDER BY DATE
    ) SELECT 'all apps' as target, date as datapoint_time, days_07 as datapoint_value FROM allTables
```

Comment: Why don't you just paste the query into the Web UI and let BigQuery check the syntax for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing one more closing bracket right before SELECT
Should be

```
WITH allTables AS (
    SELECT 
        UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(DATE)) AS DATE, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN period = 7  THEN users END) AS days_07 
    FROM (
        SELECT
            activity.date AS DATE,
            periods.period AS period,
            COUNT(DISTINCT user) AS users                                                   
        FROM ( 
            SELECT 
                activity.date AS DATE, 
                periods.period AS period, 
                COUNT(DISTINCT user) AS users 
            FROM ( 
                SELECT
                    DISTINCT DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros)) AS DATE,
                    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS user 
                FROM `hidden.*` 
                CROSS JOIN 
                    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event 
            ) AS activity 
            CROSS JOIN ( 
                SELECT 
                    DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros)) AS DATE 
                FROM `hidden.*` 
                CROSS JOIN 
                    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event 
                GROUP BY event.timestamp_micros 
            ) AS dates 
            CROSS JOIN ( 
                SELECT period FROM (SELECT 7 AS period) 
            ) AS periods
            WHERE 
                dates.date >= activity.date 
            AND 
                SAFE_CAST(FLOOR(DATE_DIFF(dates.date, activity.date, DAY)/periods.period) AS INT64) = 0 
            GROUP BY 1,2 
        ) GROUP BY DATE ORDER BY DATE
    )
) SELECT 'all apps' AS target, DATE AS datapoint_time, days_07 AS datapoint_value FROM allTables
```

Wanted to share super simple way of dealing with such type of "issues"
1. Copy troubled query to Query Editor
2. Make sure proper SQL version is picked (optional but better to have it done)
3. Now you can use Code Folding feature. You can collapse (fold) code fragments reducing them to a single visible line. In this way, you can hide the details that, at the moment, seem unimportant. If and when necessary, the folded code fragments can be expanded (unfolded). While folded - you can observe your code leaving implementation details aside and focusing on structure, etc. Also it helps in identifying bugs like in your case
[image]
4. Then you can use brackets matching feature of Editor (as below)
[image]
to clearly see that matching bracket is missing
[image]

Btw, BigQuery Mate has feature called Show Outline that also can help in many cases when you have bushy query an want to high level "picture". It is available in Mate panel and via contextual menu

[image]

Comment: Now it's throwing a `Unrecognized name: activity at [7:13]` error.

Comment: @JoeScotto - 1) one question at a time! looks like this question is answered! 2) before asking next question - really - please try to troubleshoot your stuff first. sorry for saying this - but it looks like you are using SO to outsource your work. We are here to help you, not to do your work! Don't take it personally - just try to comply with rules of SO

Comment: What are you talking about, I didn't downvote anything.

Comment: fyi - i removed few of my comments above